# When is it not safe to use multiprocessing/multithreading during OOP?

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, multiprocessing

In a current project I would be performing a set of calculations on a dataset. The dimension and shape of the dataset has been going through constant updates and changes, therefore I am thinking of creating a data object, and defining magic methods for the object. This way, when the dataset changes again, I get to keep the operational part of the code constant, only having to update the data object's magic methods.

I have heard that multiprocessing/multithreading is generally not supported for OOP. However is this still the case if I do not create nested objects?

Comment: "I have heard that multiprocessing/multithreading is generally not supported for OOP." This is not true. Also note, that python is a purely object-oriented language, *everything* is an object, so one cannot really avoid object-oriented code. Finally, multithreading and multiprocessing are different things, and you should not think of them as interchangeable

Comment: Multi-threading is “not safe” when shared state is mutated without appropriate guards - doesn’t matter if it is “OOP” or not.

Comment: @user2864740 could you elaborate on what you mean by guards?

Comment: “guards” = appropriate algorithms and thread-related access (locks, mutex, atomic, cmpx, volatile etc) to guarantee correct program execution regardless of thread/process execution order and interrupts. Actual Python code in CPython always has a multithreading guard through the GIL (and will execute as an atomic unit): however, *logical concurrency errors can still occur with code that is not written ‘aware’ of side-effects that occur in different contexts*, even when such contexts might be guaranteed to run mutually exclusively.

Comment: Re, "Python code in CPython always has a multithreading guard through the GIL." The purpose of the GIL is to make the Python interpreter itself thread-safe. It is _not_ intended to provide any measure of thread safety to the Python application. If it happens to provide some minimal memory visibility guarantees, that's only by accident, and it does not do anything at all to prevent one application thread from looking at or changing data that has been put into a temporary, invalid state by some other application thread.